# Where does LaTeX check for installed packages?

Tags: packages

When I use `\usepackage{<package_name>}`, what directories does LaTeX check for the `.sty` file for `<package_name>`? I'm asking this because I have a set of "configurations" that I always place in the preamble of my files and it would just be a lot easier to load all of that from a `.sty` file.

In my experience, it checks the directory of the `.tex` file and the regular install directory (in my case `~/.local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex`), but I was wondering if there are any other options.

Not sure if it matters but I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a user (rather than root) install of TeXLive.

Comment: You can use `kpsewhich --progname=pdflatex --show-path=tex` which should give a lot of pathes. But normally texmf-local/tex/latex or texmfhome/tex/latex should be fine (texmfhome is normally somewhere in your home directory, `kpsewhich --expand-path=$texmfhome`)

Comment: It depends on the installation.  The real question is "Where does TeXlive check for packages?"

Comment: Differently-phrased question, but basically the same: [packages - Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the relative path for the package.

```
\usepackage{Folder/Bruh.sty}
```

Comment: Hi, please do you can explain better your solution?

Comment: The Folder is a folder, athough it could also be a file _path_. Bruh.sty is the package (_it doesn't have to be bruh_)

Comment: Could the relative path also be an absolute path? (e.g.: `~/Documents/package-name.sty`)

Comment: I run LaTeX with Overleaf, so I don't know.

Comment: The `\usepackage` command expects a name not a path. See [How can I properly resolve relative paths in \`\usepackage\`?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/123999)

Comment: Even if a path works, using a relative path requires that all of your main tex files are at the same depth from the root `/`.